# MVC 3 Route question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to put in some new routes but not sure where to start. What I would like to do is to have my routes translate as follows:

```
/transport class A/23   translated to   /info/classes/A-23
```

I understand the basics of using MapRoute but can I do things like the above?

I hope someone can give advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me that you're actually after something like [UrlRewrite](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) since you're going from one Url to another.

But MVC doesn't rewrite Urls - it maps them to controller actions based on route patterns you provide.

So, if you're asking if you can split up the first url to a controller/action pair (with parameters) then of course you can. You just set up a route with the necessary parameters in the right place.  So you could call `MapRoute` with something like (I would use hyphens for the spaces):

```
/*route pattern:*/ "transport-class-{class1}/{class2}" 
/*with route defaults:*/ new { controller = "Info", action = "ViewInfo" }
```

Then you could write a controller as follows:

```
public class InfoController : ControllerBase
{
  public ActionResult ViewInfo(string class1, string class2)
  {
    //presumably get model data from the class parameters here
    //and pass it as parameter to below:
    return View();
  }
}
```

Although it would depend also if the `transport` and `class` constants in this route are actually also variable I guess - in which case you could push those down as route parameters, and into the parameter list of your controller method.

Comment: @Miguel Campos - glad to be of help :)